# Sci Fi novel on another planet with an investigator modified to not be able to show emotions

Tags: story-identification

So about 10 years ago I read a paperback novel that I cannot remember the name of. It was sci Fi, main character was a investigator, had been modified to not be able to show emotions except through his hands going cold. The book took place on another planet where there were humans living on the surface and a subterranean species living below. Lots of the details get lost but the main character sets up a peace by the end of the book only to be told a bigger threat is coming. Any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome John, please take our [tour] and refer to our [help] as and when for guidance. Enjoy Sci-Fi and Fantasy. (From review)

Comment: Did his hands glow faintly blue? (Maybe some other tale is flickering in my subconscious)

Comment: Can't remember a glow, if you can recommend the title I can check.